# How does python's random.Random.seed work?

Tags: python

I'm used to typing `random.randrange`.  I'll do a `from random import Random` to spot the error from now on.

For a game involving procedural generation (nope, not a Minecraft clone :p) I'd like to keep several distinct pseudo-random number generators:

- one for the generation of the world (landscape, quests, etc.),
- one for the random events that can happen in the world (such as damage during fight).

The rationale being that I want to be able to reproduce the first, so I don't want the second one to interfere.

I thought `random.Random` was made for that.  However something is puzzling me:

```
import random
rnd = random.Random()
rnd.seed(0)
print [random.randrange(5) for i in range(10)]
rnd.seed(0)
print [random.randrange(5) for i in range(10)]
```

produces two different sequences.  When I do `rnd = random` then things work as expected, but I do need several generators.

What am I missing?

Comment: It actually took me a few minutes to spot that too. Don't feel bad happens to all of us, glad it's solved :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It works almost exactly as you tried but the rnd.seed() applies to the rnd **object**

just use

```
rnd = random.Random(0) # <<-- or set it here 
rnd.seed(7)
print [rnd.randrange(5) for i in range(10)]
```

or by setting the global seed, like this:

```
random.seed(7)
print [random.randrange(5) for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass the seed to the constructor of `Random`:

```
>>> import random
>>> rnd = random.Random(0)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 6]
>>> rnd = random.Random(0)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 6]
>>> rnd = random.Random(1)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[1, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]
```