# How does the python random.seed work

Tags: python, random

I was following this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009657/1890488

He has this as outcome

```
>>> import random
>>> rnd = random.Random(0)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 6]
>>> rnd = random.Random(0)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[9, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 5, 6]
>>> rnd = random.Random(1)
>>> [rnd.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
[1, 9, 8, 2, 5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 0]
```

I have few problems

1. why did first two sequence are same
2. when we pass 1 as argument dos it mean then how does the first value come as 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two sequences are the same because you seeded them with the same value. This is a **feature**.

Settable seed enables you to intentionally repeat your sequences by reusing the same seed. This can be used, for example, to implement a game replay exactly equivalent to the original, although the game uses a random number generator for in-game encounters or for some AI decisions.

Comment: so it means that, if i give the same seed then every `n` iteration will be same for any number of randomnumber generators

Comment: @user196264097 Yes, if you give the same seed, you will get the same sequence out of the generator. This is how pseudo-random number generators work.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is just a pseudorandom generator. This is **a function** (in a mathematical sense) that has nice square distribution. Common practice is to use system time in milliseconds as a seed:

```
rnd = random.Random(int(round(time.time() * 1000)))
```